# Configurable product overrides simple products qty increments

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, quantity

I have a client who uses configurable products to allow customer to chose between a series of simple products. Magento has a default feature for "Qty increments", which limits the quantities allowed to purchase to products of the value specifier. I.e. if you set "Qty increments" to 5, you're allowed to buy 5,10, 15 etc.

My issue is that the "Qty increments" specified for the configurable product overrides that of the simple products. Is it possible to change this, so that the "Qty increments" of the simple products are used instead?

Comment: It's possible to rewrite the model to accommodate this, but you will have to hardcode the configurable product increments to 1. ;-)

Comment: Great, thank you. I managed to find a solution :-)

Comment: @Splurk feel free to share your solution with us